# How to install Geany 2.0 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, text-editor

How to install Geany 2.0 on Ubuntu 22.04? It's been released recently but doesn't seem to have ready to use builds as of now.

Comment: You can use flatpak https://flathub.org/apps/org.geany.Geany

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install Geany 2.0 on Ubuntu will be to install the Snap version, once the Snap is updated. Since Geany 2.0 was released four days ago only, it may be unrealistic to expect it is now already available as Snap. You may need a few weeks of patience before you can install the application as a Snap.

A second best way may be to enable Flatpak on your Ubuntu installation, and install the Flatpak version from Flathub. The Flatpak version already is updated to version 2.0.

The website of Geany publishes source code only. While one can compile the source code to install it, the methods above are recommended for less technical users.